# Async Request-Response Algorithm with response time limit

Tags: algorithm, asynchronous, message, message-passing

I am writing a Message Handler for an ebXML message passing application.  The message follow the Request-Response Pattern.  The process is straightforward: The Sender sends a message, the Receiver receives the message and sends back a response.  So far so good.

On receipt of a message, the Receiver has a set Time To Respond (TTR) to the message.  This could be anywhere from seconds to hours/days.

My question is this: How should the Sender deal with the TTR?  I need this to be an async process, as the TTR could be quite long (several days).  How can I somehow count down the timer, but not tie up system resources for large periods of time.  There could be large volumes of messages.

My initial idea is to have a "Waiting" Collection, to which the message Id is added, along with its TTR expiry time.  I would then poll the collection on a regular basis.  When the timer expires, the message Id would be moved to an "Expired" Collection and the message transaction would be terminated.

When the Sender receives a response, it can check the "Waiting" collection for its matching sent message, and confirm the response was received in time.  The message would then be removed from the collection for the next stage of processing.

Does this sound like a robust solution.  I am sure this is a solved problem, but there is precious little information about this type of algorithm.  I plan to implement it in C#, but the implementation language is kind of irrelevant at this stage I think.

Thanks for your input

Answer (score 1):

Depending on number of clients you can use persistent JMS queues.  One queue per client ID.  The message will stay in the queue until a client connects to it to retrieve it.

I'm not understanding the purpose of the TTR.  Is it more of a client side measure to mean that if the response cannot be returned within certain time then just don't bother sending it?  Or is it to be used on the server to schedule the work and do what's required now and push the requests with later response time to be done later?

It's a broad question...